# During testing 'Error during cleanup of component' error pops up

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

> I have a menubar component whichh is the parent component which loads
>   the other inner component.
>
> I have mocked all the inputs and services , i have also spied on
>   router.navigate so it prevents loading new components.This works in
>   all other components with no issues.
>
> Now in menubar component an error pops up: 'Error during cleanup of
>   component '.
>
> Then it loads a child component which inturn loads another app online.
>   This breaks the tests,and get errors.
>
> i can prevent loading of child components in all other components
>   expect  menubar component. Is there any way i can prevent this.
>
> (note:I AM WRITING THE TEST FOR AN ALREADY DEVELOPED APP.THIS MAKES
>   THINGS COMPLICATED).
>
> Mocking the components using overrideComponent()
>
> no_errors_schema
>
> Creating a mock class with the same name as the child component and
>   specifying it in the declarations part
>
> menubarcomponent.spec.ts

```
 describe('UNIT TEST : MenubarComponent', () => {   

   let component:MenubarComponent;   

   let fixture: ComponentFixture<MenubarComponent>;  

   let router, layoutSvc, auth, orgSettings, user, loginSvc;


   beforeEach(async(() => {

     TestBed.configureTestingModule({

       imports: [TestModule],

       declarations: [],

       providers: [{ provide: AuthService,useClass:AuthServiceMock}],
       schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
   })
   .compileComponents();   }));

 beforeEach(() => {

   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MenubarComponent);

   component = fixture.componentInstance;

   router = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Router);

   layoutSvc = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(LayoutService);

   auth = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AuthService);

   fixture.debugElement.injector.get(SettingsService);

   user = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);

   loginSvc = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(LoginService);

   spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');

   spyOn(router, 'navigate');

  fixture.detectChanges();  
});

it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();  

});


 });
```

> html
>
> ```
>    <app-monthly-plan-expire-soon></app-monthly-plan-expire-soon>
> ```
>
> the child component is called so and it loads an another app live on
>   the internet.
>
> Menubar component should run the tests without any errors and not load
>   any child components.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error while testing as well. I edited the log dictated in this merge:
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/22162/commits/5ad159fc277bd77b4394fdbf0cbf258eda61748b

Which added the error that was being caught in addition to the componentInstance that was throwing the error. It made it immediately obvious in my case what was going wrong, hopefully it can do the same for you!